# CentOS 7 ec2 smtpd - Client host rejected: Access denied

Tags: postfix, smtp, sasl, roundcube, centos7

I've been trying to figure this out for hours and can't quite wrap my head around it.

I have a mail server on an ec2 instance running CentOS7 that has postfix, courier (authlib and imap), sasl, amavisd, spamassassin and roundcube configured on it. When I `telnet localhost 25` then I can successfully send emails even out of my ec2 instance.

I installed roundcube to make it easier for users to read/send emails. I can login no problem, I can see my emails and can read them (so imap is working properly). My issue however comes when I want to send emails out from roundcube (over smtps port 465). It pops up with `unable to set recipient` and the following error message:

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[127.0.0.1]: 554 5.7.1 <unknown[127.0.0.1]>: Client host rejected: Access denied;
```

Full stack of email sending attempt:

```
Nov  6 08:11:26 ip-172-31-9-181 postfix/smtpd[5651]: connect from unknown[127.0.0.1]
Nov  6 08:11:26 ip-172-31-9-181 postfix/smtpd[5651]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[127.0.0.1]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Nov  6 08:11:26 ip-172-31-9-181 postfix/smtpd[5651]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[127.0.0.1]: 554 5.7.1 <unknown[127.0.0.1]>: Client host rejected: Access denied; from=<sender@mydomain.com> to=<reciever@mydomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.mydomain.com>
Nov  6 08:11:26 ip-172-31-9-181 postfix/smtpd[5651]: disconnect from unknown[127.0.0.1]
```

This is my roundcube configuration in config.inc.php

```
$config['default_host'] = 'ssl://localhost';
$config['default_port'] = 993;
$config['imap_auth_type'] = 'LOGIN';
$config['image_force_ns'] = true;

$config['smtp_server'] = 'ssl://localhost';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_helo_host'] = 'mail.mydomain.com';
```

I've tried setting

```
$config['smtp_user'] = '%u';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '%p';
```

But that causes an SASL error:

```
Nov  6 08:24:01 ip-172-31-9-181 postfix/smtpd[5705]: connect from unknown[127.0.0.1]
Nov  6 08:24:01 ip-172-31-9-181 postfix/smtpd[5705]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[127.0.0.1]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Nov  6 08:24:01 ip-172-31-9-181 postfix/smtpd[5705]: warning: SASL authentication failure: client response doesn't match what we generated (tried bogus)
Nov  6 08:24:01 ip-172-31-9-181 postfix/smtpd[5705]: warning: unknown[127.0.0.1]: SASL DIGEST-MD5 authentication failed: authentication failure
Nov  6 08:24:01 ip-172-31-9-181 postfix/smtpd[5705]: disconnect from unknown[127.0.0.1]
```

Which has gotten me so confused that I can't figure out what is even causing it? is it smtp, sasl or something else? All services required are enabled and start up with no problems.

This is my output of `postconf -n`

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
delay_warning_time = 4h
disable_vrfy_command = yes
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
local_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
local_destination_recipient_limit = 300
local_recipient_maps =
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
masquerade_domains = mail.mydomain.com mydomain.com
masquerade_exceptions = root
maximal_backoff_time = 8000s
maximal_queue_lifetime = 7d
mime_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/body_checks
minimal_backoff_time = 1000s
mydestination =
mydomain = mydomain.com
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_helo_timeout = 60s
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl, permit
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtpd_recipient_limit = 16
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/unime.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/unime.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
soft_bounce = no
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_alias.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_mailbox.cf
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

This is my `master.cf` file:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated.reject_unauth_destination,reject
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination,reject
    -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous,noplaintext
    -o smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options=noanonymous
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
    -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
    -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous,noplaintext
    -o smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options=noanonymous
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
    -o content_filter=
    -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
amavis    unix  -       -       -       -       2       smtp
    -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
    -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
    -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
    -o max_use=20

127.0.0.1:10025 inet n - - - - smtpd
    -o content_filter=
    -o local_recipient_maps=
    -o relay_recipient_maps=
    -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
    -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
    -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
    -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
    -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
    -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
    -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
    -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks
```

And this is my `sasl2/smtpd.conf` file:

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login cram-md5 digest-md5
log_level: 7
allow_plaintext: true
auxprop_plugin: sql
sql_engine: mysql
sql_hostnames: 127.0.0.1
sql_user: xxxxx
sql_passwd: xxxxx
sql_database: xxxxx
sql_select: xxxxx
```

Any help would be appreciated to finding out the issue behind it. If any more info is needed to find out the cause, then let me know.

Comment: Are you able to send mail from commandline `telnet localhost 25`?

Comment: @clement Yes, I can successfully send email from `telnet localhost 25`

Comment: hmm Can you configure your `username` and `password` as `$config['smtp_user'] = 'username'; $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';` and check if it is working. What i could infer is `roundcube` is not authenticating and `smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject` restriction is hit.

Answer (score 2):

As @clement already stated the following configuration from the smtps part of the master.cf matches with a reject: `-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject`

So configure roundcube to authenticate with the user credentials.

Or allow localhost to send mails e.g. in the master.cf with permit_mynetworks in both the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` and `smtpd_client_restrictions` as first parameter like so: `permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject`

Comment: Apologies on the late reply. I did give your solution a try but frankly it resulted in the same `recipient rejected` error. So as a solution of my own, I changed `smtp_server` to just `localhost` and the port to 25 and it seems to work pretty okay.

Comment: Try to remove `cram-md5 digest-md5` from the mech_list in sasl/smtp.conf. And also set `$config['smtp_auth_type']` according to @sebix answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo in your `master.cf`:

```
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
...
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated.reject_unauth_destination,reject
```

Note the `.` after `permit_sasl_authenticated`.

Should be

```
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
...
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination,reject
```

Also usually port 587 is used to submit mails for authenticated users:

```
$config['smtp_port'] = 587;
```

Also, play with `smtp_auth_type` parameter:

```
$config['smtp_auth_type'] = '';
$config['smtp_auth_type'] = 'AUTH';  
$config['smtp_auth_type'] = 'LOGIN';
```

according to your Postfix-SASL configuration.

Comment: There must not be a whitespace in a parameter list after `-o` in the master.cf. Postfix would otherwise only parse the option up to the whitespace. Please edit you answer accordingly that it is `-o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination,reject` without a whitespace.

Comment: Oh, thanks @sebokopter. It wasn't obvious to me yet, but you're right of course. In my `master.cf`s I just adopted to the existing style and thus made it always right :)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, I added my ip range to `mynetworks` file in `/etc/postfix` directory and it solved the problem, eg:

```
vim /etc/postfix/mynetworks
```

then go to the end of the file and add your ip address block -
eg: `91.0.0.0/8`

then save and restart postfix.